# How to stick down border of JScrollPane with the Jframe or JPanel?

Tags: java, swing

I mean when I resize the frame to the left or right side the table automatically resizes itself but I want the same future when I resize it from down or up sides of the table. There is scroll for down and up but I want default size to be smaller.

In fact `aJScrollPane.setSize()` doesn't work, `aJPanel.setSize()` too. Can you help me?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to restrict the number of rows the table displays by default, you can use [JTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setPreferredScrollableViewportSize%28java.awt.Dimension%29). For example for 10 rows you can do the following:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(
        new Dimension(table.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize().width, 
                10 * table.getRowHeight()));
```

Note however, table rows can have variable heights. Also note, that hard-coding sizes in general can have side effects.